# ActiveAdmin still does subquery_for_count even when pagination_total: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, kaminari

I have a redshift table in the billions of records, lets call it `SomeModel`.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Redshift::SomeModel do
  menu parent: 'Redshift'

  config.filters = true
  config.sort_order = '' <-- I figured out this removes the order by, which is intentional

  filter :message_uuid, as: :string
  filter :epoch, as: :numeric

  index pagination_total: false do
    column :message_uuid, sortable: false
    column :epoch, sortable: false
    column :status, sortable: false
    actions
  end
```

However as you can see, the table gets called 3 times. 2 of which is doing some sort of sub query. (this is local log)

[image: screenshot of logs]

When I explore the trace on newrelic, you can see the 3 queries are very costly. A 46 second response time is no beauno. I'm not really sure what the 2 counts are doing, and why its done twice. How can I remove those count queries?

[image: new relic trace]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a longstanding bug having to do with how the [collection helper queries collection size](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/helpers/collection.rb) — the current definition triggers unnecessary/redundant COUNT queries, and it's called several times when building an index page with paginated results. I submitted a PR to ActiveAdmin, but you can try overriding the helper in your project with this:

```rb
module ActiveAdmin
  module Helpers
    module Collection 
      def collection_size(c=collection)
        return c.length if c.is_a?(Array) || c.limit_value.present?

        c = c.except :select, :order
        c.group_values.present? ? c.size.size : c.size
      end
    end
  end
end
```